# Blocking null value entries into database

Tags: mysql, database

I want a script to block the entry of null valued into a database . i am able to do this by some changes in the code , but my intention is not change it in the code rather write a script which can be run to accomplish this task

for example table " book " has author_name , price , title .
i don't want to allow any entry into the database that has null  author_name

Comment: you can modify the table structure and put the author_name as not null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `NOT NULL` clause in column's definition. For example -

```
CREATE TABLE book (
  author_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  price decimal(19, 2) DEFAULT NULL,
  title varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

This works like a constraint.

---

A workaround to constraint **blank** values -

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
  AFTER INSERT
  ON book
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF author_name = '' THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '02001'
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Blank value is not allowed'; -- Raise error
  END IF;
END
```

Documentation - [SIGNAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html) statement.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I have done this , if i assign blank value, it is being updated to the datatbase , how to encounter that problem.

Comment: The blank is not NULL. if you want to constraint blank values, then you need to write a trigger which raises the error.

Comment: thanks Devart , But this has to be added in the code ryt ? i want some script that can be run outside of it , not changing the code .

Comment: If I understood your question - Yes, you need to create this trigger. That is because of MySQL does not support CHECK CONSTRAINT.

Comment: I may have not explained my problem properly , here it is , i need some script(.bat file) to be run after i install my application such that whenever i enter a blank value and try to save it into my  database it should not be possible .

Comment: I see two ways - to constraint this in database (see the answer), and to constraint this input in application. In both cases you should make some changes (in database or in application).

Answer (score 0):

You can set your table up in a way, that it rejects such entries:

```
alter table book change column author_name <DATATYPE> NOT NULL;
```

see more here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/alter-table.html

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

```
create_definition:
    col_name column_definition 
column_definition:
    data_type [NOT NULL | NULL] [DEFAULT default_value]
      [AUTO_INCREMENT] [UNIQUE [KEY] | [PRIMARY] KEY]
      [COMMENT 'string']
      [COLUMN_FORMAT {FIXED|DYNAMIC|DEFAULT}]
      [STORAGE {DISK|MEMORY|DEFAULT}]
      [reference_definition]
```

Your column_definition should look like

```
author_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
```