# Blocking the entry of null values into a database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Database which i am accessing it through an application .the application takes all kind of values including Blank(My mistake :( should have constrained this in my application only). I want to run a script such that it blocks the entry of null values into my database .

for example : Books is my database  with columns author , price , title 
             I want to block null author name entry ,
   I have used a trigger as shown below;

DELIMITER |

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1  AFTER INSERT ON books
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF NEW.author = '' THEN    
    delete from books where author = '';
    END IF;      
  END;
|books
DELIMITER ;
```

This script meets the objective of blocking null values , But  has some inconsistency (after certain point i'm not able to access the database at all , i can neither enter a value nor access one ).
Can any one tell me what might be the problem.

Comment: Is there any error message? I don't think this is a good idea.. It's better to implement the constraint in the application.

Comment: Do you want `NULL` values to be discarded or an empty string `''`?

Comment: Empty string needs to be discarded .

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you could achieve this-
1)Change the trigger to BEFORE INSERT
and if the author name is null, return false
This would stop the application from inserting blank author names.

2)Alter the table schema, and add a constraint not null to the author name.

Refer [Blocking null value entries into database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872630/blocking-null-value-entries-into-database?rq=1)

Comment: By using Before Insert the same problem occurs , and by altering schema how can i block blank values ?

Comment: ALTER TABLE books
    ADD CHECK (author!='')

Comment: which language is your application written in?
It would be simpler to check the author name and skip the insertion if it is null or blank

Comment: My application is in C# , I know the method to do it in the code but i cant make changes in my app now , hence want an alternative.

Comment: @harin04 kindly mark an answer as accepted if it helps you or answers your question
It will be helpful to other users who visit the site in the future.
Same goes for your other questions as well- you havent accepted an answer in any one of them